# How to make a massive selected update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a list of values(deviceID) and I need to make an MySQL Query to update a column value, I can do the query in the following way

```
UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID='Jhon' 
WHERE accountID='Delivery1' AND 
      (deviceID='1234' OR deviceID='1235' OR deviceID='1236')
```

That's is a simple example but some accountID have more than 500 devicesID so I'm looking for a shorter SQL statement
So, There's any way to pass the list of deviceID's to the SQL server?

Something like

```
UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID='Jhon' 
WHERE accountID='Delivery1' AND 
      (deviceID=('1234','1235','1236))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

if the datatype of `deviceID` is numberic, single quotes are not required.

maybe `IN` for multiple values not `=`

```
UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID = 'Jhon' 
WHERE accountID = 'Delivery1' AND deviceID IN (1234,1235,1236)
```

or if the ID are in sequence use `BETWEEN`

```
UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID = 'Jhon' 
WHERE accountID = 'Delivery1' AND deviceID BETWEEN 1234 AND 1236
```

Comment: Thanks, for your fast answer. The first option seems to be the better. If all are numbers,  The single quote is needed?

Comment: @E_Blue if the data type is numeric then wrapping with single quote isn't needed. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too:

```
UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID='Jhon' 
WHERE accountID='Delivery1' AND deviceID > = 1234 AND deviceID <= 1236
;
```

Comment: The values are not consecutive, that's just an example. Thanks any way.

Comment: Then you are better off having the list in IN but even they are not consecutive, whatever between these a certain two IDs will fall through ;) `IN` still better

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work, if using php:

```
$ids = join(',',$deviceIDs);

$sql = "UPDATE Clients.Devices 
SET assignedUserID='Jhon' 
WHERE accountID='Delivery1' AND deviceID IN ($ids)";
```

Comment: Actually I'm using .NET 2010 and the list is from a DataGridView(selected cells). Any way is nice to learn, may be I can use that code some time, so I'm wondering now, The join in the first line its a SQL  statement or PHP function? I'm starting with SQL and currently I don't know how to create complex functions, like iterative ones.

Comment: That's actually a php function, which joins all array items in array <pre><blockquote>$deviceIDs</blockquote></pre>, formatted: 1234,56456,5676 etc.